# Check JSONArray for specific value

Tags: android, json

In my Android Activity I am getting a JSONArray via HTTP containg usernames. 
The Array looks like this:

```
[{"username":"Julia"},{"username":"Anja"},{"username":"Hans"},{"username":"Sophia"},{"username":"Sarah"}]
```

I want to check in the Android Activity if a given username already exists.

What would be the most efficient way to do it? Or do I have to iterate over the whole array?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

use a simple String function/method like

```
private boolean userexists(JSONArray jsonArray, String usernameToFind){
    return jsonArray.toString().contains("\"username\":\""+usernameToFind+"\"");
}
```

Comment: you can also return jsonArray.toString().contains( usernameToFind ); for a cleaner and shorter solution.

Comment: Sorry but this is i.m.o. a bad solution. What if a username contains partly another username? So if you have "Anja" as a username to find, but another user is called "Anjatovic". It would lead to inaccurate results.

Comment: @Thermometer   this is why the code answer looks for start and end quotes.

Comment: Woops, totally missed that, my bad!

Comment: Is it possible to get an Index of an object from array that has matched?

Comment: Is this an optimal solution in the case of a large array?

Comment: Whats with the downvote?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: I'm searching for a solution but IMO (IN MY OPINION) this seems not so good. What happen if the string look like `{"username":     "Anja"}` or tab, or line break...?