# How to set limit for a hibernate query

Tags: hql

How can I set a limit to this hql query? When I add the limit keyword in the query, an error is thrown.

```
 @Query("from voucher v where  v.voucherType.typeDescription = :typeDescription and v.denomination = :denomination")
 public List<Voucher> findByVoucherTypeAndDenomination(@Param("typeDescription") String typeDescription,@Param("denomination") BigDecimal denomination);
```

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery="true", value=...)

Answer (score 15):

When you call your query add the following:

```
.setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(limit);
```

`setFirstResult` is the (optional) offset, `setMaxResults` is the limit.

**UPDATE**

Docs:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)

If you use entityManager, it can be like:

```
entityManager.createQuery("yourQuery").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(5);
```

Comment: Please wat does the firstresult in setfirstresult(firstresult) represent

Comment: @SamuelAnertey it says which result row to start with. In this case, that call is saying "give me up to 5 results, starting with result 0". In the case of MySQL, it would be the equivalent of ending your query with "limit 0,5".

Answer (score 3):

You can use two method of Query object.

> setFirstResult() // offset
>
> setMaxResults() // limit

but you can not use it in HQL because limit is database vendor dependent so hibernate doesn't allow it through hql query

Answer (score 1):

Limit was never a supported clause in HQL. You are meant to use setMaxResults().